# bullets data (ul li data) disappears WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress

I need to add some data to the WordPress page Using LearnPress. adding data through copy paste from MS-word document.some listed data is missing in website.but it is showing in admin page

[image]

In output showing as below some listed data is missing.

[image]

Any Guess?

Comment: Can you have a link please?

Comment: @MukeshRam http://csonlinetrainings.com/courses/mobile-application-testing-online-training/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the issue is in your custom-style.css

You need to remove :

```
div.course-tabs ul li:nth-child(3n) {
display: none;
}
```

from the css file.